# Can I force MySQL to use on-disk internal tables?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, temp-tables

If I know in advance that the internal tables created by a query can't fit into the available memory, can I force MySQL to use on-disk internal tables, to avoid in-memory creations and then HEAP to DISK conversions? Is one way to temporarily

```
set tmp_table_size = 0
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is made specifically your your case:

```
SET big_tables = ON
```

(And turn it off afterward.)

before the `SELECT`.

Caveats: Deprecated in MariaDB 10.5 in favor of `SET tmp_memory_table_size = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Setting your tmp_table_size is the correct way. Minimum value is 1024, I don't think setting it to 0 will work.